# Populate Dropdown list from a web service without code

Tags: services, navigation

I know that in Drupal a drop down list field can be populated with taxonomy terms, but is there a way without having to go custom (custom PHP development) to populate a dropdown list from the results of consuming a web service?

Say I consume a web service that returns the weather for the current week (7 days), I would like to populate the data returned into a dropdown list so that whenever the data is changed at the web service it is automatically reflected in my list.

Is there way to do this in the Drupal UI?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it in code call the webservice in a custom module process the results and pass it to the template for display as you need